# Creating tables for user authentication - room for improvements?

Tags: mysql

At the moment I'm developing a web application. For that, I need to create a database for user authentication.

I have something like the following in mind:

```
create table users
(
id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY_KEY(id),
UNIQUE(username)
);

create table roles
(
id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
role VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY_KEY(id),
UNIQUE(role)
);

create table user_roles
(
user_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
role_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY_KEY(user_id)
UNIQUE (user_id, role_id),
);
```

Passwords are fixed size but I use `varchar` because I've read somewhere that in a table where you have both `char` and `varchar` columns, the `char` columns get converted to `varchar`.

Also, would it be beneficial to use FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS?

Comment: You misspelled the `mysql` tag. Twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use `SMALLINT`s for IDs. Seriously. Why would anybody do that!? Use a larger integer type.
2. The primary key on `user_roles` isn't going to work. Make `(user_id, role_id)` the primary key and put separate (non-unique) indexes on the fields you will be querying on.
3. You could add foreign keys that link `user_roles` to the other tables. If you use `ON DELETE CASCADE`, it'll even delete the stale links if you ever delete a user or a role.